# SQL Server 2019 support in DataGrip (can't connect to an instance)

Tags: sql-server, datagrip, sql-server-2019

I don't seem to be able to connect to a locally installed SQL Server 2019 instance using DataGrip (2019.3).
No matter which auth I use (domain or SQL), I get the following error:

***"The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [08S01] The server SQL19 is not configured to listen with TCP/IP"***

URL I'm connecting to is ***jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQL19***.
If instead of "SQL19" part I use SQL Server 2016 instance name, it works fine,
so I'm assuming I'm configuring the connection correctly, unless there's some tweaks I need for SQL 2019?

I can connect to a 2019 instance from SSMS and applications, it's available via TCP/IP etc.

Comment: are you getting any error? may drive is missing!

Comment: edited the question to include more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, SSMS does not require TCP/IP, that's why it works. For DataGrip, you need to turn it on.

Perhaps this doc will help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html

Comment: no but SSMS can be configured to connect over TCP/IP

Answer (score 10):

Answering my own question with some details (@moscas answer is correct, but I feel details may still be useful for somebody).

TCP/IP seems to be disabled by default in SQL Server 2019, and SQL Configuration Manager turned out to be not easy to find: it doesn't show up when you do regular search in "Start" menu and it doesn't exist under SQL Server's folder in the menu (wtf, Microsoft?).

You need to go Computer Management (this does show up in search) -> Services and Application -> SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration, choose your instance and enable TCP/IP.

Datagrip starts to work then.

Comment: Also note that there's a separate "SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit)", so make sure you check both if you can't find it at first

Answer (score 2):

In additional to enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager. I also had to enable the Sql Browser service under Sql Service Service.